# Adding buttons inside of edit text android

Tags: android

I have created a relative layout and placed list view on top, editable text below list view and 1 button on the left of editable text and one button on the right of editable text.

Looks something like this.
[HOW ITS LOOKING AT THE MOMENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m68ky.png)

But I want the buttons to be placed inside the editable text view. Can someone please help, really appreciate your time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="app.com.date.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:id="@+id/listview1"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@null" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/listview1" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/listview1"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/text1" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

but, it should look like this

[HOW IT SHOULD LOOK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrZ1w.png)

Thanks for reading . appreciate your time.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm seeing the difference. The only really apparent difference is that your Views aren't styled. Why put the buttons in the EditText rather than having them left and right? You're not editing the buttons

Comment: Yes, it's just for the purpose of styling. I want to make the edit text like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrZ1w.png

Comment: If that's the case, consider making a parent horiztonal `Linear Layout` and nest your Button, EditText, Button inside. Create a border around the `Linear Layout` and style the EditText to be a bit more blank

Comment: Whoops meant horizontal - edited that :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:id="@+id/listview1"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:divider="@null" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/listview1" />

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/listview1" />

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```